# You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is my first django project so apologies if I'm not explaining myself well. I'm trying to write some unit tests.

This code works as intended:

```
from unittest import TestCase


class TestModel(TestCase):
    def test_CalculatePercentage(self):
        assert 1 == 1
```

However, when I try to import something from the application, i.e:

```
from investor.models import Investor
```

I get the `ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.` error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 60, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 676, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 633, in _callTestMethod
    method()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
    raise self._exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\lbrusokas\Documents\Dev\website\website_env\src\webapp\investor\tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from investor.models import Investor
  File "C:\Users\lbrusokas\Documents\Dev\website\website_env\src\webapp\investor\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 87, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 38, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr1w1.png) is my project structure.

I've seen many posts and suggestions regarding this, such as adding environment variables, calling settings.setup(), configuring pycharm, enabling django support, etc, but nothing has worked for me.

What other options do I have to fix this or is it occuring somewhere else?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you getting this error all around the app or just at the tests.py?

Comment: Just at the tests.py Everything else works fine as expected.

Comment: Wait, how are you trying to run this test?

Comment: I use Pycharm run unittest utility (right click on the document, and there is an option near debug to run unit test).
However, if I run via terminal (python manage.py test)  I get this error 
`
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
EEEE ERROR: webapp.investor (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
ImportError: Failed to import test module: webapp.investor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp.investor'
`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same virtual environment as pycharm?

Comment: Yes, just setup brand new environment, configured pycharm, installed requirements.txt, website works fine. Unit test fails again

Comment: Gotcha, answer incoming :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import Python's Testcase with `from unittest import TestCase`. You need to import Django's. Replace it with

`from django.test import TestCase`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this before, I tried that too. This only gives me a slightly different error: 
'
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
'
Also, this time I don't even need to import anything from the application, it fails by having ` from django.test import TestCase ` alone

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your project structure. Can you type dir at the directory where your manage.py is, then share the result?

Comment: Amended original question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr1w1.png

Comment: Can you try: `python manage.py test investor.tests --settings=webapp.settings`

Comment: Good news, the error disappeared: 
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

However, just to quickly test it, I've added another test, but it still says that only one test ran.

Comment: I copied the content of investor.tests to stock.tests and ran 
`python manage.py test stock.tests --settings=webapp.settings` 
it still says 0 tests ran. I struggle to understand this behavior

Comment: At the end, I figured out, there was a problem with Pycharm configuration (still don't know what). I moved my project to Visual Studio Code, ran all commands from the terminal and everything works like a charm. All tests are discovered and I can use `manage.py test` to find and excecute all my tests. A big thanks for your help @engin_ipek